# when i launch my android studio emulator in tool window, its all fine, but when i launch it in standalone app, the emulator screen is too small

Tags: android, flutter, emulation

[this image shows how the emulator looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWFek.png)

i tried reinstalling everything but it still didnt work
i tried to change compatibility of qemu x86  to system instead of application but the emulator resolution was so bad so i deleted all SDK files and redownloaded everything again to another folder (E) instead of (C) and the emulator still doesnt work properly as it used to.
i think the problem started when i deleted some folders in C:\Users\myuser\.android\avd\
i deleted all the emulators from there because they were taking too much space, i didnt have storage, so i deleted all then i reinstalled the one that i liked and then i started having this problem.

btw zooming in doesnt work either, ive tried almost everything, nothing made it work

Comment: Try resize emulator window from it's corners(rounded corners)...

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: choose a older system image( api 28 for example ) and create a new emulator

Answer (score 0):

1. When creating new Virtual deice you can see Hardware resolution:

[image]

2. In AVD Configure window in AndroidStudio you can see your emulator hardware resolution:

[image]

3: You can resize emulator window from corners:

[image]